# Oracle ADF input form, start as empty

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am new to ADF and Jdeveloper, so this might be a trivial question, even though i searched and could not find an appropriate solution.

I want to create an input form that starts as empty then on button click the user can add a row in the database.

I know how to do it with the form starting as an edit form, but i want the form to start as empty.

I am not using taskflows, just a simple JSF page to create a record.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the page to come up without actually fetching data, you can delay the execution of the data fetching like this:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/delay_method_execution_when_us
If you want it to come up with an empty row already in place, you can add a createInsert method call before the navigation to the page in your controller layer.

Comment: hi shay, i managed to get the empty form, but when i try to insert a new record, using create and insert or create, i can see the row added from the web interface, but it does not get persisted in DB. BTW i am following your tutorials on oracle insider for BC and Faces Components, so the bc part is build following the tutorial.

Comment: To save the row into the database you'll need to invoke the commit operation in your page. This is shown in part 3 of this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_55/jdtut_11r2_55_3.html